# After migrating to Android Studio, I get the "Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class" error

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-gradle-plugin

So until recently I was developing an Android app with a server component with Eclipse; dependency management was done with Maven. I now wanted to try to move to Android Studio (most recent version of the studio and the SDK).

In Eclipse I had 3 projects: a server project (for Tomcat; Apache Jersey, Jackson and Hibernate), a "common" project which included the model classes, and the Android project for the App. The Android project referenced the "common" project so that I could use the model along with the Jackson Annotations in the Android App as well. This all worked perfectly.

Now I imported the Android project into Android Studio and streamlined the dependencies. The "common" project became a local Maven module which I included in the build.gradle of the new Android project. This is the build.gradle:

```
...

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'at.schulupdate:schulupdate-common:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.android:android-iconify:1.0.9'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:1.1.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
}
```

The POM of the "common" project looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>at.schulupdate</groupId>
    <artifactId>schulupdate-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-jstlel</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And gradle dependencies shows:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- project :viewpagerindicator
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.3.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.3.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.3.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.3.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 (*)
+--- at.schulupdate:schulupdate-common:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.6.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|    |    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
|    |    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    |    |    |    \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2
|    |    |    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.5.Final
|    |    |    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
|    |    |    |    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|    |    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA
|    |    |    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    |    |    \--- org.jboss:jandex:1.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.5.Final (*)
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
|    |    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate4:2.4.2
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0 -> 2.4.2
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.2
|    +--- org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-jstlel:1.2.1
|    |    +--- org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-spec:1.2.1
|    |    \--- org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-impl:1.2.1
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
+--- com.joanzapata.android:android-iconify:1.0.9
+--- uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:1.1.0
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
\--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2 (*)
```

The gradle build in Android Studio succeeds! But when I want to deploy it to a device I get the following error:

> :schulupdate:transformClassesWithDexForDebug trouble processing
>   "javax/transaction/Status.class":
>
> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when
>   not building a core library.
>
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in
>   your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If
>   you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this
>   is the most likely explanation of what's going on.
>
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
>   namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a
>   non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not
>   work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with
>   future versions of the platform. It is also often of questionable
>   legality.
>
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>   appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution,
>   as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the
>   "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an
>   application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail
>   to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers
>   who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once
>   they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this
>   problem.
>
> If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a core
>   package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to repackage
>   that code. That is, move the classes in question into your own package
>   namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict with core
>   system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help you in this endeavor.
>   If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an indication that
>   the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain, suffering, grief,
>   and lamentation.
>
> 1 error; aborting

Now I understand that my "common" project includes transitive dependencies like org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final which define classes in the javax.transaction namespace. But I don't really understand how to solve this problem. I still need the code from that package on the device, right? And it's no core package at all, so it is certainly not included on Android devices. Should I define my "common" project as core library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I found the solution myself. Since Hibernate is not available on Android, I needed to exclude that dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile('at.schulupdate:schulupdate-common:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'org.hibernate'
    }
    compile 'com.joanzapata.android:android-iconify:1.0.9'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:1.1.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
}
```